# Excel Summing Multiple Cells Based Off Row & Column Indicators

Tags: excel

So, what I have is an excel sheet that is automatically generated by a program, so reformat is not an option:

[Example Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcYBz.gif)

General format of this excel will stay the same, with some additional rows depending on the day.

I’m trying to create a formula that I will use from another worksheet (I can handle linking from another workbook) that will give the total number of Boxes for that day.
For example, the correct answer for this day would be 85.

I have tried a few formulas but they have not worked for me.. I am most likely missing something. I tried getting all numbers relative to the “Totals:” cells, and just distinguishing the “* Box” columns with SUMIF but that didn’t work either.

Ideally: Have the formula look at cells in the same row as the “Totals:” rows(blue), but only in the Box Columns(orange) to pinpoint all the (green) cells and add them all up for a grand total.

Colors were just added for visual reference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to post 1 or 2 of your formulaes that didn't work, that ways it will be easier to locate and explain where exactly did you go wrong.

Comment: I did some googling and tried to relate it to my spreadsheet. They may have been just completely wrong. But one I did try (before I was trying to use Totals row as well) was SumIF: =SumIF(G5:T5,"Box*",G6:T230) - T230 was just an example I tried in the event that I had more data

Comment: Can you please condense this into a smaller text-based example so that anyone hoping to help doesn't have to manually retype out all your data? See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I have replaced my link with a more simple link, I'm not sure if that's what you meant.. basically the numbers themselves don't matter as long as there is a working example.

Comment: @Patchell13, you have mentioned that the general formatting of the excel will remain the same with some additional rows, does this mean we can have hard references to the columns where "* Box" value occurs, rather than creating a formula which scans through the first row to find the qualifying columns? Once we decide to hard-code the columns, it will be a lot more easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes Columns should stay the same, but the location of the Totals will move up and down depending on the day. So they should always be columns I K M O Q & S.

Comment: If there is a way to include a copy-able table to make it easier for others I'm not sure how to do it. In order to not offend any potential question answerers. *I appreciate the attempt on whoever it was that deleted theirs.*

Comment: @Patchell13, just another line of thought - you can do down the path of PivotTables and see if that makes things any easier

Comment: @BharatAnand How so? On the source workbook? I don't think so.. my intent is to figure out what formula will work to get the total (85) without having to actually using the source workbook. And having a Monthly Overall Worksheet that pulls from these source workbooks as I save them daily.

Comment: @Patchell13, the idea was to add a pivottable in your destination workbook with reference to your source data workbook. Ofcourse, each time your source data changes you will have to refresh the pivottable. This was more of an idea to think in this direction in case you haven't already considered it. Then it maybe possible to reference the DATACUBE variables of that pivot to do your work. You can ignore this as you have already got a working solution now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There may be a way to make it more compact, but I have tested and this works if your columns do not change

`=SUMIF(A:A,"Totals:",I:I)+SUMIF(A:A,"Totals:",K:K)+SUMIF(A:A,"Totals:",M:M)+SUMIF(A:A,"Totals:",O:O)+SUMIF(A:A,"Totals:",Q:Q)+SUMIF(A:A,"Totals:",S:S)`

Comment: This does work :) if there is a way to condense this formula that anyone knows I would appreciate it. But this works in the meantime. Thank you very much Bharat, I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Try this array formula: `=SUM(IF($A$6:$A$23="Totals:",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" Box",$I$5:$S$5)),$I$6:$S$23)))`. Do not forget to do a `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to make it evaluate correctly

Comment: @Patchell13, here's another one without using the array formulaes. Although now I am thinking which is the optimal solution in terms of performance et al: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$6:$A$23="Totals:")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("* Box",$H$5:$S$5)))*($H$6:$S$23))`

Comment: I am currently using the newest suggestion you made here. This is much easier to edit as save new source excels (formula name changes every day with the date). I very much appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

After a quick test something this might work (as an array formula):

[image]

Comment: I had just attempted something like this. Unfortunately the Program the generates this report puts a big break before and after the text: [See Here](https://imgur.com/a/OdXR5d0) Is this fixable with this solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "big break" but if it's reproducible then you'd just need to make some adjustments to the "RIGHT()" part.